# R 3.1.2 - Paste metacharacters to use within a function

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function which lets me easily replace strings that begin with certain characters. I have written the following function, but R doesn't seem to recognize the metacharacters as soon I paste them to a string.

```
library(plyr)

vector <- c("cow", "chicken", "elephant", "garden", "banana")

map.start = function(vector, oldwords, newwords) {
  oldwords2 <- paste("^", oldwords, ".*", sep = "")
newvector <- mapvalues(vector, oldwords2, newwords)
return(newvector)
}

vector <- map.start(vector, "eleph", "donkey")
print(vector)
```

When executing these commands, the following error occurs: The following `from` values were not present in `x`: ^eleph.*

So, R does not seach for words beginning with 'eleph', but does not recognize the metacharacters and searches for an exact match of "^eleph.*", which does not exist of course. Can someone tell me if (and how) it is possible to combine metacharacters and strings within a function? Thanks!

edit: I tried using gsubfn for replacing multiple strings, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I still doing wrong?

```
library(gsubfn)

vector <- c("cow", "chicken", "elephant", "garden", "banana")

map.start = function(vector, oldwords, newwords) {
  oldwords2 <- paste("^", oldwords, ".*", sep = "")
  newvector <- gsubfn(oldwords2, newwords, vector)
  return(vector)
}

vector <- map.start(vector, c("eleph", "gard"), c("donkey", "ninja"))
print(vector)
```

Comment: See also the `gsubfn` function from the package with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace function `mapvalues` by function `gsub` from `base R` (which will work with `regex`):

```
map.start = function(vector, oldwords, newwords) {
    oldwords2 <- paste("^", oldwords, ".*", sep = "")
    newvector <- gsub(oldwords2, newwords, vector)
    return(newvector)
}

vector <- map.start(vector, "eleph", "donkey")
print(vector)
#[1] "cow"     "chicken" "donkey"  "garden"  "banana"
```

***If you need to pass a vector of items and a vector of replacement***, you can combine `gsub` with a `for` loop:

```
 map.start = function(vector, oldwords, newwords) {
        oldwords2 <- paste("^", oldwords, ".*", sep = "")
        for (i in 1:length(oldwords2)) {
           vector <- gsub(oldwords2[i], newwords[i], vector)
        }
        return(vector)
 }
 map.start(vector, c("eleph","chick"), c("donkey","duck"))
 #[1] "cow"     "duck" "donkey"  "garden"  "banana"
```

***Another option without a for loop***

```
 map.start = function(vector, oldwords, newwords) {
        oldwords2 <- paste("^", oldwords, ".*", sep = "")
        corresp <- do.call("rbind", mapply(function(x,y) cbind(ind=which(regexpr(x, vector)!=-1), new=y), 
                                           x=oldwords2, 
                                           y=newwords, 
                                           SIMPLIFY=F))
        vector[as.numeric(corresp[, "ind"])] <- corresp[, "new"]
        return(vector)
 }
 map.start(vector, c("eleph","chick"), c("donkey","duck"))
 #[1] "cow"     "duck" "donkey"  "garden"  "banana"
```

Comment: Just a guess, but the plural name of the arguments may indicate that he needs a vectorized solution (which is not handled by `gsub`). Maybe add some `gsubfn` solution, which should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @nicola: correct, I chose mapvalues to replace multiple stings at once. I will delve into gsubfn then, thanks!

Comment: @Tim, I don't know the package `gsubfn`, so I edited my answer with a `for loop` solution to pass vectors. I'm not particularly proud of this loop and still looking for a way to get the desire result with a nice vectorized solution...

Comment: @CathG: thank you anyway! I tried using gsubfn myself, but I cannot get it to work either (see edit).

Comment: @Tim, as I understand it, arguments `pattern` is the same as in `gsub`. I guess the subtility is in the `replacement` and the `backref` arguments...

Comment: @Tim, `multigsub` from package `qdap` seemed promissing but it doesn't seem to accept `regex`...

Comment: @Tim, see my edit for a "vectorized" solution (don't know if it's more efficient though...). This solution creates a matrix with correspondances between indices of the `vector` and `newwords` based on `oldwords2`, it then replaces the "old words" by the "new" ones.